# Do I have to pay a license fee for Berkeley DB?

Tags: license, berkeley-db

I'm planning to use Berkeley DB in a mobile application. Will I need a [license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB#Licensing) even if the application is distributed freely in the iPhone and Android markets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/licensing-098979.html

Our open source license permits you to use Berkeley DB, Berkeley DB Java Edition or Berkeley DB XML at no charge under the condition that if you use the software in an application you redistribute, the complete source code for your application must be available and freely redistributable under reasonable conditions. If you do not want to release the source code for your application, you may purchase a license from Oracle. For pricing information, or if you have further questions on licensing, please contact us at berkeleydb-info_us@oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB#Licensing):

> As of July 2011, Oracle's list price for non-copyleft Berkeley DB
>   licenses varies between 900 and 13,800 USD per processor.